# Rename ASP.NET_SessionId

Tags: asp.net

I need to rename the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie created by default by ASP.NET. Let's say I want it's named "foo". Is it possible?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Add to your web.config:-

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieName="foo" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Any way of doing this without changing the web.config?

Comment: Super Working Fine :)

Answer (score 15):

You can set this in the `<sessionState>` configuration setting in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieName="myCookieName" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Just spotted as well...fixed...appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

See [sessionState Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx). look at the cookieName attribute, which will change it from the default of "ASP.NET_SessionId".

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do it in your web.config file:

```
<sessionState cookieName="foo" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall it correctly but I think you can rename it by changing the `web.config` file.

Seach for the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) element of the `web.config`.

Comment: downvoted because `<sessionState>` is not included by default in web.config in most cases, not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has got here looking for a solution compatible with ASP.NET Core, this can be normally specified within the Startup, as a parameter of the CookieBuilder, e.g:

```
 .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                {
                    IsEssential = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                    Name = "MyOwnCookieName"
                };
            })
```