# Renaming or Removing sc.ASP.NET_SessionId from .Net MVC Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sessionid

I have received review comment rename the  **ASP.NET_SessionId** to something which hides the technology which we use in development of the application.since it's showing Asp.net in it's name.
I was able to rename the **ASP.NET_SessionId** to some thing else by help of the link
[Rename ASP.NET_SessionId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017144/rename-asp-net-sessionid)

But there is one more cookie  *sc.ASP.NET_SessionId*  I am not sure from where this cookie is coming from.

I have searched whole application for hints of  **sc.ASP.NET_SessionId** but I am unable to find.Please help me to rename that cookie.Or shall I remove that cookie?

[image]

Comment: Delete it from your browser, then check from network tab which http response does set it if you navigate again on your site. (Search `Set-Cookie` header in responses.) Maybe this could help you understand what emits this cookie in your application.

Comment: I have checked as you mentioned.But I am not finding the place where this cookie is being added in the application.There is no code written to add this cookie.

Comment: This is why I suggest you to first find the offending http response setting it, by inspecting every http responses you receive in your browser after having deleting the cookie from your browser. It will at least ensure you which site emits it. Since you are investigating on `localhost`, any other site you are using on any other port may set it. (Port does not segregate cookies.)

Comment: I have inspected as you suggested.It's set in a request header of the first controller action call.
Still unable to find the root cause.The screen shot added in the below url.
http://imgur.com/7mfcqAi

Comment: Do you use ["SessionCam web analytics application from ServiceTick"](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/sc.ASP.NET_SESSIONID)? (This is the first link I have got on google.fr by searching your cookie name.)

Comment: No.We are not using.Even I got the same results when I checked.

Answer (score 1):

Now with all this discussion in comment, I can only add as an answer that all my sites have their session cookie renamed (using `<sessionState ... cookieName="..." />` in web.config), and none of them emits an unwanted cookie name.
And I am doing that for quite a long time, from fx 2 to 4.5.2, with webforms and MVC v3 to 5.2, ...

Maybe have you some specific binary component emitting it, as a specific session provider or any other non-default module / action filter lib / whatever.

Try reproducing the trouble with a brand new empty MVC application, `cookieName` redefined. Check it works, then add your actual application dependencies, frameworks, ..., one after another, checking at each addition if the trouble starts kicking in.
(Beware of not getting fooled by another local navigation on your actual applications, since on localhost they will set the cookie for your test app too.)

**Side note:** your screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkstA.jpg does not showcase the adequate http header. You should find which url respond a `Set-Cookie` response header. Your screenshot shows a `Cookie` request header.
When a cookie is in request header, it means it is already too late, some previous response from some application on localhost has already set it.

Response header `Set-Cookie` example:
[image: Set-Cookie header]