# Session Lost after loading aspx page in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iframe

I have MVC project as the main project in which I made one folder say FolderA which has a project in web forms.

I have declared the session on a controller say

```
session["usertype"] ="5";
```

And this session I cannot access directly in FolderA as its web form so passed user type session through the query string.
In one of the view, I call the aspx page through iframe tag.

```
 <iframe src="/demo.aspx?u=utype" />
```

the problem is that when this aspx page loads in iframe the all the session throughout  the application (declared on the controllers are lost), I get null reference error  when I redirect to another action method

Comment: Are the MVC and web forms sites two different applications, each with their own web.config?  If yes, try [changing the name of the session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017144/rename-asp-net-sessionid) in one of the sites so they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: @JohnWu It does work, Thank  you, but I getting new error ----  It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS , now looking into it

Comment: @JohnWu actually it is not working , the session is not lost as the iframe failed to load due to the above error

Comment: Sounds like there is only one application and therefore you get an error when you have two web.configs.  So if there is only one application, there should only be one session.  Does `demo.aspx` do anything that might drop the session cookie, e.g. a session fixation mitigation? What do you see in your browser debug logs in terms of cookies?