# Session is cleared in App A when App B is opened

Tags: .net, session, iis

I have two .NET core apps hosted in IIS each in their own application pool.  Here's the behavior:

1. Open app A and it works as expected.  Save, search, etc.
2. Open app B in a new tab and it works as expected.
3. Switch back to app A and it fails immediately as its session data isn’t there. Apparently opening app B affected app A.
4. Restart app A again in the same tab and it works.
5. Switch to app B and it no longer works.

Both apps are 2.1 apps targeting framework 4.6.1.

ConfigureServices has:

```
services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(450));
```

Configure has:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use two diffrent browsers? 1 for site A and another for site B.

Comment: Yes, it fails as described in the question when I open the apps in separate Edge browsers.  It works though when App A is opened in Edge and App B is opened in IE.

Comment: It also works in separate Edge browsers if one of the tabs is InPrivate.

Comment: Is there any relationship between your App A and App B? Are they under the same domain? Do you have any code in App A about clearing the session?

Comment: @samwu: These are separate apps in IIS.  Here are examples of the urls:   https://intranet.xxxxx.com/Intranet/dotNET/hiv_stage and https://intranet.xxxxx.com/Intranet/dotNET/kpi_stage.  We've been using this convention for years and web forms and MVC 5 apps work correctly.  There isn't any code that clears session.  Session variable names are unique for each application. I don't have access to IIS.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Please check whether your sessionstate timeout has expired? and application pool timeout will also cause the session to be cleared, you should check it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it sounds like your two apps are competing for the same session cookie. This would explain the behavior you have observed, especially how the problem disappears when you use two different browsers.

To test this hypothesis, open app A, and examine the Cookies. (In Chrome, for example, you can view the Cookies on the Application tab of the Developer console.) Look for a Cookie that represents the active session ID. By default, this cookie is named `ASP.NET_SessionId` in .NET. Take note of the Domain for that Cookie. Now perform the same test on app B. Does the Cookie have (1) the same name and (2) the same domain? If so, that is your problem.

You have already identified two easy workarounds for this problem:

1. Open the apps in different browser (e.g. Edge and IE)
2. Open one app in an Incognito browser

As for a permanent fix, the easiest way is probably to rename the Session ID for one or both apps to make sure they do not conflict. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017181/11838196) shows how to do this in Web.Config, as an example.

Comment: I looked into the cookie name and domain and they are the same for both apps. But then it's the same cookie name and domain for the web forms and MVC 5 apps where we don't have this issue.  Tired of it all, I changed the cookie name in the two core apps and it works!  Thanks!  I don't have or want a web.config in my solution -- I changed it in Startup:  services.AddSession(s =>
            {
                s.Cookie.Name = "ASP.NET_HIV.Session";
                s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(480);
            });